# Managed 2GP Package CI/CD

Tags: 2gp, cicd, 2gp-ama

We're looking to adopt a CI/CD flow similar to this Salesforce diagram.

[image]

The CI part is pretty much there but with 2GP all packages are created as beta packages which can't be upgraded in our Test/UAT org which means removing the package manually but that is quite a time consuming manual process. The other approach might be to promote the package as soon as it's created so that it can be deployed into our Test/UAT org but that doesn't seem right to be promoting a package before it's even been tested but is that how we're expected to do this?

Any advice here would be appreciated

Comment: We have adopted an approach where we generate scratch orgs for all stages up to QA, where QA leverage a custom sfdx data loading plugin (based on the tree import/export but enhanced to support more types of object and more objects to import, along with a mechanism to offset dates and date/time values during import). Beyond that we expect to leverage newly created/refreshed orgs into which we can deploy our 2GP, though TBH we've not yet hit that stage. As such I'll be interested to see what others have been doing or are planning to do.